# Vertically centering 3 paragraphs with CSS

Tags: html, css, center

I'm just a beginner. I managed to horizontally center my div, which contains 3 paragraphs with this:

```css
div p {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 50%;
    color: white;
}
```

How can I get them vertically aligned, with text being right aligned? Pic related.

[image]

```html
<div class="imperio">
    <p>Império<br>
    dos<br>
    Sabores</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div p {
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: i want to center vertically, not horizontally

Comment: Write you Html as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use styling for the div container to make it vertically center aligned.

Here's a [working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qpbJ2/).

Btw, you really should use `text-align: center` instead of your current styling to make it horizontally center.

Comment: OK, the vertical align code that I used to center the div tag should help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by making the `div` a flexbox. `align-items` CSS property will centralise the elements horizontally and `justify-content` will centralise the elements vertically. Right now the `flex-direction` is `column`. But if you change it to `row`, the behaviour of `justify-content` and `align-items` interchanges.

I know you said that you're just a beginner and flexbox can be too much for you as of now but you can always memorise these four properties to center stuff both vertically and horizontally inside a division. Later you can read about the flexbox in depth. But if you wish to give it a shot, refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

```css
div {
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

div p {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis lorem gravida, pretium erat a, aliquet lorem. Maecenas hendrerit suscipit augue blandit iaculis.  
    </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis lorem gravida, pretium erat a, aliquet lorem. Maecenas hendrerit suscipit augue blandit iaculis.  
    </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis lorem gravida, pretium erat a, aliquet lorem. Maecenas hendrerit suscipit augue blandit iaculis.  
    </p>
</div>
```